# Reading file line by line in jsp

Tags: java, forms, jsp, parsing, webforms

I have a text file containing various information such as name, age, address and ID.

```
Tommy
14
Gold coast
11994452
```

I would like to be able to pass the data into a jsp webpage and edit it using a web form.

I have a working file reading in jsp format that is able to read the file and display the information on the webpage, however i am confuse as to how does the web form edit various information such as name in the text file.

**Example: Tommy has a new address and i would like to use a web form to change the value in the text file

```
<%
String fileName = "/test/putty.txt";
InputStream ins = application.getResourceAsStream(fileName);
try
{
if(ins == null)
{
response.setStatus(response.SC_NOT_FOUND);
}
else
{
BufferedReader br = new BufferedReader((new InputStreamReader(ins)));
String data;
while((data= br.readLine())!= null)
{
out.println(data+"<br>");
}
} 
}
catch(IOException e)
{
out.println(e.getMessage());
}
%>
```

Should i define the file by lines ? Eg line 1 = name , line 2 = age, line 3 = address and write back to the specific line ? If so how can this be done ?

Thanks in advance

Comment: learn about MVC style java frameworks such as struts, spring MVC and stripes.  Do not try to put code into your jsp.